# Meet someone at the time when you are not working

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-usage

How to name a period of time, that you want to meet a person you work / study with at, which is not during the studies or work?

> Do you want to have a lunch **(off-work?)**?
>
> I can help you with that **(off-work?)**.
>
> I usually study in my **(off-work?)** time.

Is that a comprehensible phrase? Or there are better alternatives?

Comment: Do you want to have a [_private_](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/private) lunch (with me)?

Comment: @alwayslearning doesn't it give the romantic connotation?

Comment: If someone wants a working lunch, they will call it a 'working lunch'. Just inviting to 'lunch' implies it is not work-related.

Comment: @NigelJ the solution should be more general. "I can help you with that off-work", for example.

Comment: @Eduard When I am eating lunch, or doing personal study, or socialising I am (self-evidently) not working. I cannot see the point of your distinction.

Comment: You could say ***"outside of work hours".***

Answer (score 1):

We generally use *free* in a variety of forms to cover your examples:

> Are you free for lunch?
>
> I can help you with that when I'm free.
>
> I usually study in my free time.

Answer (score 0):

You could ask, "can I help you with that outside of work hours?"

You could also say:

- I usually study in my free time.
- Can I help you with that in my spare time?
- Can I help you with that outside of work?

Answer (score 0):

I would normally phrase this as:

> Would you like to have lunch on your next day off?
>
> I can help you with that on my [next] day off?
>
> I usually study in my spare time.

Non-working time can be called a number of things: "*Day off*" or "*spare time*" are probably the most common in the UK.

- **Spare time**: Time when you are not working or do not have anything you must do.
- **Day off**:  A day when you are not required to work
- **Off day**: A day when you do not perform as well as usual.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the words 'before' or 'after' to convey your thought, if you're not certain of the time.

Example - 
"Do you want to have lunch after work/studies?"

Or you can use the exact time for asking. Like

"Do you want to have lunch at 2 O'clock?"